# Empty subfolder inside a folder not getting zip archived and only files present in the folder or non-empty subfolders getting zip archived

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the function that is being called to create zip archive of a folder from a location, The issue is that if the folder has a subfolder with no files in then the empty subfolder is being totally ignored and only the file in the archive folder is being returned but when the subfolder is not empty then the sub folder is getting created.

for example, if the folder structure is like

folder1
|
|***> sub_folder1(empty sub_folder)
|***> file1.xlsx

Then the zip archive has just file1.xlsx in it ignoring the sub_folder1

def get_zip_sub_folder(folder_path, zip_filename):

```
s = BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            rel_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, folder_path)
            zf.write(file_path, rel_path)

    for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(folder_path):
        for dir in dirs:
            dir_path = os.path.join(root, dir)
            rel_path = os.path.relpath(dir_path, folder_path)

            # Check if the directory is empty
            if not os.listdir(dir_path):
                zf.write(dir_path, rel_path)

resp = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename
return resp
```

@api_view(["GET"])

def zip_downloads(request):

```
try:

    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/" + request.GET.get('link', "")
    zip_filename = "RawData.zip"
    resp = get_zip_sub_folder(path, zip_filename)
    return resp
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("download API failed with error\n%s", traceback.format_exc())
    return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

My expectation is

if the folder structure is like

folder1
|
|***> sub_folder1(empty sub_folder)
|***> file1.xlsx

Then the zip archive should have empty sub_folder1 as well as file1.xlsx